# Closed-form solution for maximum likelihood estimator logit/probit

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I need some clarification on where I can expect a closed-form solution. My research so far suggests the following:

- Logit model for binary dependent variables: no closed-form solution
- Probit model for binary dependent variables: no closed-form solution

Source: Ben Lamberts video on the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WflqTUOvdik. (Though he says in the video that the solution is typically "analytical", I guess from the context, that he actually meant "numerically")

- PDF of logistic distribution as likelihood function for continuous dependent variables: no closed-form solution
- PDF of the normal distribution as likelihood function for continuous dependent variables: $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y$ (thus provides us with the same estimator as OLS, if the error term is normally distributed)

Can you verify that? In particular, I am interested in whether it is correct that the logistic model has no solution for the continuous dependent variables. Could that change if I assume some more specific assumptions, like in the case of the normally distributed model (error term normally distributed)?

Comment: What do you mean by Logit/Probit "for continuous dependent variables"? Both of these models are meant for binary response variables. Or do you mean [*fractional* Logit/Probit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/216122)?

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out. I simply meant, that we take the pdf of the normal distribution as likelihood function (unlike the probit model). Same for the logistic model.

Comment: Are you asking if a Gaussian GLM with the logit link function has a closed form solution?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. But if I understand correctly, I am not asking for any combination of logistic and Gaussian, but rather for the two separately.

Comment: If you want to "take the pdf of the normal distribution as likelihood" you end up with a [simple Gaussian linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/379210).